# Über die Wendung "über alle Maßen"

Tags: grammatical-case

> Worttrennung: Maß, **Plural: Ma·ße**

Warum heißt es *"über alle Maßen*" statt "*über allen Maßen*" bzw. *"über alle Maße"* ? Oder wie lässt sich die Diskrepanz zwischen den Fällen des Adjektivs und des Substantivs sonst erklären?

Comment: Weil es eben nicht um _das Maß_, sondern um _die Maße_ geht. Das sind verschiedene Wörter. Dazu muss man nur mal ins Wörterbuch schauen.

Comment: Das ergibt schon SInn. Vielen Dank

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: könnte es sein, dass nicht alle Wörterbücher einen eigenen Eintrag zu dem völlig veralteten Begriff *die Maße* haben? Wollten wir da nicht [großzügiger mit dem Schließen wegen "General Reference" sein](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/wann-soll-ich-welchen-schlie%c3%9fgrund-bei-fragen-nach-%c3%9cbersetzungen-bedeutungen-u)?

Comment: Hm. In Google eingegeben, erster Treffer führt zum Duden. So schwierig war es nicht. Was muss denn noch erfüllt sein, um ein Close-Vote zu rechtfertigen?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Die Suche nach *"Wendung Maßen"* bei Google hätte ein noch viel besseres Sucherergebnis, nur leider ohne Antwort. ;)

Comment: Wieso sollte man auch "Wendung Maßen" eingeben, wenn man nach "über alle Maßen" sucht? Gibt man das ein, was man sucht, so führt der allererste Link bei Google direkt zu Duden mit einer Liste von Wörtern. An achter Stelle tritt "Maßen" auf. Da klickt man drauf und findet die Antwort: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masze.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: dann such halt nach *"was bedeutet Maßen in der Wendung über alle Maßen"* - immer, wenn German Language auf Platz 1 der Suchergebnisse steht, ist das **richtig super** für uns - wenn dann keine Antwort kommt, schadet das unserem Ansehen mehr, als eine nicht so schwierige Frage, die nicht geschlossen wurde.